# How to create a grouped list on flutter without any dependency

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

How to create a grouped list on flutter without any dependency
like list with headers

How to create a grouped list on flutter without any dependency
I am new at flutter plz help.
I am new at flutter plz help. i have a college project to complete.

Comment: are you looking 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html